# Retrieve the Package Name Instead of Publisher Name

Tags: query

Is there a way to retrieve the Package name of the installed packages in an org instead of the Publisher Name? When you query SELECT Name FROM Publisher, you'll get Docmation and Salesforce (See this screenshot: https://gyazo.com/3a2608db2d230ba66f93487487f8affb ). However, instead of getting "Docmation", I wanted to get Lightning Charts from those value. Is the Publisher Name considered as Package name? Coz I am thinking that there is a possibility that 2 different package name may have 1 same Publisher.

Answer (score 0):

The correct object to look for installed packages is `PackageLicense`
Name isn't currently  available in this object.

```
SELECT NamespacePrefix, Status, UsedLicenses, AllowedLicenses FROM PackageLicense
```

Comment: Hmm. Okay. Just thought whether there's other way of retrieving them.